# Using Where IN with STRING_SPLIT and an aggregate count in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a simple `Select` statement:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    COUNT(*) AS AuthorCount, PMID, dbid
FROM  
    dbo.[Publication.PubMed.Author]
GROUP BY 
    PMID, dbid
HAVING 
    (dbid = 500) AND (COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY 
    PMID
```

This statement returns all of the rows with an `AuthorCount`. I would like to filter it with only records that have the PMID number that is in the comma separated string

Such as adding a

```
WHERE CAST(PMID AS NVARCHAR(15)) IN STRING_SPLIT('28049775,28864564,28049810,27921451,29043651,30001498,27702896,27897198',',')
```

I've looked at C. Aggregation by values at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 but that did not help

I would like to only end up with the sub set of rows that is in the comma separated string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following trick, that lets you search the column value against a comma separated list using `LIKE`:

```
WHERE (',' + '28049775,28864564,28049810,27921451,29043651,30001498,27702896,27897198' + ',') 
    LIKE '%,' + CAST(PMID AS NVARCHAR(15)) + ',%'
```

Other note on you query: condition `dbid = 500` does not relate to an aggregate function so it would better fit in the `WHERE` clause than in the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(*) AS AuthorCount, PMID, dbid
FROM  dbo.[Publication.PubMed.Author]
WHERE 
    dbid = 500
    AND (',' + '28049775,28864564,28049810,27921451,29043651,30001498,27702896,27897198' + ',') 
        LIKE '%,' + CAST(PMID AS NVARCHAR(15)) + ',%'
GROUP BY PMID, dbid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY PMID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I pulled out the dbid since I don't really need that.  This works and I'm using it but shouldn't an IN work with a STRING_SPLIT also?